# Bootstrap 3 navbar collapses when selected on mobile devices but reloads whole page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have a navbar that worked fine on desktop, but on mobile devices (or if I reduce my browser width) after selecting an item the navbar remained in place, but I want it to collapse so that the page content can be seen. I managed to fix this by adding the highlighted changes to my code below, but the problem with this solution is that it makes the whole page reload, when what I require is that the header stays in place and is not reloaded. Here is my code :

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a  class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/Home']" **data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"**><img src="./app/assets/images/football.png" style="height: 28px; display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px;">Gameplan NFLC</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a [routerLink]="['/Home']" **data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"**>Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                       aria-expanded="false">Main<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a [routerLink]="['/SuperbowlOdds']" **data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"**>Superbowl Odds</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://forum.gameplan.org.uk/viewforum.php?f=9&sid=c44a50e759b28dd287ad52a0f7609940">Forum</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My changes can be found in three places where there are links, I basically added:

```
data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"
```

to each anchor tag.  Before adding these the navbar did not collapse at all, but now the whole page reloads.

What I require is:

1. Make navbar collapsible
2. Make navbar header remain in place.

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT : You can see the site in it's current state here : http://lovelyjubbly.azurewebsites.net

Comment: Are you look into console what you hover? Maby your logo link or some other links are over button? Sometimes happen.

Comment: Please see edit above, I have included the site url, maybe that will help to find the issue

Comment: this work properly like i see

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to close nav bar after clicking/taping in some other place on the page? If so, you have to add some event listener to you document and close nav bar manualy.

Comment: On clicking on one of the 3 anchor links I want to close the div with id navbarHeaderCollapse, whilst keeping the div with class navbar-header open

Comment: Your links are not anchors. Your links are links to another page of the website. You have to handle click event, preventPropagation(), and remove necesary classes.

Comment: Profesor08, do you have an example of this?